# Linear combination of power law distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I am exploring whether a linear combination of power law distributions is also a power law distribution. Specifically, if $X \sim (\alpha -1) x_{\min}^{(\alpha -1)} x^{-\alpha}$ and $Y \sim (\beta -1) y_{\min}^{(\beta -1)}y^{-\beta}$, we are interested in finding the distribution of $Z = \rho X + (1-\rho) Y, \rho \in (0, 1)$? ($X$ and $Y$ are independent)

I tried with the moment generating function approach:

If $M_Z(t)$ is the moment generating function of $Z$, $$M_Z(t) = E[e^{tZ}]=E[e^{t(\rho X + (1-\rho)Y}]=E[e^{t\rho X}]\cdot E[e^{t(1-\rho)Y}] = M_X(t\rho) M_Y(t(1-\rho)).$$

This brings us to the moment generating functions of the power law distributions themselves:

$$M_X(s) = \int_{x_{\min}}^\infty e^{sx}(\alpha -1)x_{\min}^{(\alpha-1)} x^{-\alpha} \, dx = (\alpha - 1)x_{\min}^{(\alpha-1)}\int_{x_{\min}}^\infty e^{sx}x^{-\alpha} \, dx. $$

Like it is mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383438/characteristic-function-and-or-moment-generating-function-of-power-law-distribut), this resembles the incomplete gamma distribution, but I cannot complete the derivation. And, more importantly, I am not sure if this will help me answer the original question, i.e., is the linear combination of two power law distributions also a power distribution?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by *power law distribution*.  If you mean *Pareto distribution* then I would guess the answer would be no.  If you mean particular behaviour in the tail (on a log-log scale roughly linear on the right) then I would guess the answer might be yes.

Comment: Incidentally, power law distributions have heavy tails and some of their moments are infinite, as are their moment generating functions for all $t \gt 0$

Comment: @Henry In this case, I do mean the log-log linear behavior in the tail. And you are correct, the moments are defined only for $t<0$ above. However, I am not able to complete the proof using this or through a differentiation of the cumulative distribution function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment generating function doesn't exist for many heavy tailed distributions. In general if you take suitably normalized linear combinations of power-law distributed random variables with infinite variances (ie with tail parameter $\alpha<2$, the [generalized version of central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution#A_generalized_central_limit_theorem) shows weak convergence to a [stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) with the same tail parameter. If $\alpha\geq 2$ the linear combinations will tend to converge toward a Gaussian. Note that when $\alpha=2$ the variance may still be infinite but convergence to Gaussian is still possible. An example of a heavy tailed stable distribution is the Cauchy. All stable distributions except Gaussian have power law tails. John P. Nolan has some useful notes on his [website](http://fs2.american.edu/jpnolan/www/stable/stable.html).

Comment: Thank you for pointing towards the stable distributions...