# Evaluate this integral: $\int_{y_\min}^{\infty} (1 - ty)^{1-\alpha}y^{-\beta}dy$, $\alpha, \beta \in (2, 3)$

Tags: calculus, integration

This problem is a different approach to my earlier question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857264/linear-combination-of-power-law-distributions)

The core integral $\int_{y_\min}^{\infty} (1 - ty)^{1-\alpha}y^{-\beta}dy$ resembles the Beta function, but I am unable to get to the substitution to bring it to the correct form.

Applying integration by parts with the notation $\int udv = uv - \int vdu$, where $u = (1-ty)^{1-\alpha}$ and $v = \dfrac{y^{-\beta}}{1-\beta}$ gets me back to an integral that is similar to the original.

Applying the transformation: $ty = z$, we get $\int_{ty_{\min}}^{\infty} (1 - z)^{1-\alpha}z^{-\beta}dz$, but I am unable to reduce this further with $\alpha, \beta \in (2, 3)$

Any hints?

Comment: Try $z=1/y$. $$

Comment: *Mathematica* gives:  $-e^{-i \pi  \alpha } t^{\beta -1} B_{\frac{1}{t \text{ym}}}(\alpha +\beta -2,2-\alpha )$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the substitution $z=\frac1{ty}$, we get (let $m=y_\text{min}$)
$$\begin{align}
\int^{1/mt}_0(1-\frac1z)^{1-\alpha}t^{\beta-1}z^{\beta-2}dz & =t^{\beta-1}\int^{1/mt}_0(\frac{1-z}z)^{1-\alpha}z^{\beta-2}dz\\
& =t^{\beta-1}\int^{1/mt}_0(1-z)^{1-\alpha}z^{\alpha+\beta-3}dz\\
& =t^{\beta-1}\int^{1/mt}_0(e^{\pi i}(1-z))^{1-\alpha}z^{\alpha+\beta-3}dz \\
& =t^{\beta-1}e^{\pi i(1-\alpha)}\int^{1/mt}_0(1-z)^{1-\alpha}z^{\alpha+\beta-3}dz\\
& =-t^{\beta-1}e^{-\pi i\alpha}B(\frac{1}{mt};\alpha+\beta-2,2-\alpha)
\end{align}$$

which is the same as Mathematica's result.